# Downgrading Eclipse TestNG plugin from 7.x to 6.x

Tags: testng, testng-eclipse

I trying to downgrade the Eclipse TestNG plugin via https://beust.com/eclipse-old which is mentioned on TestNG documentation at https://testng.org/doc/download.html, but it seems to be moved/decommissioned. 
[image: TestNG Old Eclipse plugin]

Is it possible to install an older version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have moved it to a different location, please find the below link
https://dl.bintray.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse-release/

**Example:**
https://dl.bintray.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse-release/6.14.3/

Please follow the below steps:

1. Go to Install new software in eclipse:

[image]

2. Add the TestNg version that you want to install.

Example: https://dl.bintray.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse-release/6.14.3/

[image]

3)

[image]

*************** **NEW UPDATE** *********************

The link has been moved to a new link:

https://testng.org/testng-eclipse-update-site/

Versioned update site URL:

https://testng.org/testng-eclipse-update-site/7.4.0

https://testng.org/testng-eclipse-update-site/7.3.0

https://testng.org/testng-eclipse-update-site/7.2.0

https://testng.org/testng-eclipse-update-site/7.1.0

https://testng.org/testng-eclipse-update-site/7.0.0

https://testng.org/testng-eclipse-update-site/6.14.3

**Install via Eclipse Marketplace**

Go to the TestNG page on the Eclipse Market Place and drag the icon called "Install" onto your workspace.

**Install from update site**

- Select Help / Install New Software...
- Enter the update site URL in
  "Work with:" field: Update site for release:
  https://testng.org/testng-eclipse-update-site.
- Make sure the check
  box next to URL is checked and click Next.
- Eclipse will then guide
  you through the process.